# The error 'Grid index out of range' when switching between the databases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe8

This is the procedure to display the Customer Database:

```
    procedure TfrmMain.mnuCustomerClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      j: integer;
    begin

      con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
      query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
      con.LoginPrompt := False;
      con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\katiee\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');
      query.Connection := con;
      query.sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM CustDatabase ORDER BY ID';
      query.Open();
      query.First;

      sgdDatabases.colCount := 9;
      sgdDatabases.FixedCols := 0;
      for j := 0 to sgdDatabases.rowCount do
      sgdDatabases.ColWidths[j] := 100;

      sgdDatabases.Cells[0, 0] := 'ID';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[1, 0] := 'First Name';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[2, 0] := 'Last Name';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[3, 0] := 'Address';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[4, 0] := 'Town';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[5, 0] := 'County';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[6, 0] := 'Postcode';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[7, 0] := 'Telephone No.';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[8, 0] := 'E-Mail';

      row := 1;
      while not query.EOF do
      begin
        ID := query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
        firstname := query.FieldByName('First Name').AsString;
        lastname := query.FieldByName('Last Name').AsString;
        address := query.FieldByName('Address').AsString;
        town := query.FieldByName('Town').AsString;
        county := query.FieldByName('County').AsString;
        postcode := query.FieldByName('Postcode').AsString;
        telno := query.FieldByName('TelNo').AsString;
        email := query.FieldByName('Email').AsString;

        sgdDatabases.Cells[0, row] := ID;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[1, row] := firstname;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[2, row] := lastname;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[3, row] := address;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[4, row] := town;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[5, row] := county;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[6, row] := postcode;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[7, row] := telno;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[8, row] := email;

        sgdDatabases.RowCount := sgdDatabases.RowCount + 1;
        row := row + 1;
        query.Next;

         end;
       end;
```

This is the procedure to display the Employee Database, which is basically identical except "SELECT * FROM EmplDatabase":

```
    procedure TfrmMain.mnuEmployeeClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i: integer;
    begin

      con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
      query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
      con.LoginPrompt := False;
      con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\kasio\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');
      query.Connection := con;
      query.sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM EmplDatabase ORDER BY ID';
      query.Open();
      query.First;

      sgdDatabases.colCount := 9;
      sgdDatabases.FixedCols := 0;
      for i := 0 to sgdDatabases.RowCount do
      sgdDatabases.ColWidths[i] := 100;

      sgdDatabases.Cells[0, 0] := 'ID';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[1, 0] := 'First Name';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[2, 0] := 'Last Name';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[3, 0] := 'Address';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[4, 0] := 'Town';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[5, 0] := 'County';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[6, 0] := 'Postcode';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[7, 0] := 'Telephone No.';
      sgdDatabases.Cells[8, 0] := 'E-Mail';

      row := 1;
      while not query.EOF do
      begin
        ID := query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
        firstname := query.FieldByName('First Name').AsString;
        lastname := query.FieldByName('Last Name').AsString;
        address := query.FieldByName('Address').AsString;
        town := query.FieldByName('Town').AsString;
        county := query.FieldByName('County').AsString;
        postcode := query.FieldByName('Postcode').AsString;
        telno := query.FieldByName('TelNo').AsString;
        email := query.FieldByName('Email').AsString;

        sgdDatabases.Cells[0, row] := ID;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[1, row] := firstname;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[2, row] := lastname;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[3, row] := address;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[4, row] := town;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[5, row] := county;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[6, row] := postcode;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[7, row] := telno;
        sgdDatabases.Cells[8, row] := email;

        sgdDatabases.RowCount := sgdDatabases.RowCount + 1;
        row := row + 1;
        query.Next;

        end;
      end;
```

When I run the program, I can open either of the databases on the first click, but then if I click again on either of the Customer or Employee buttons or try to change the database, the following error shows: "Project ProjectQuote.exe raised exception class EInvalidGridOperation with message 'Grid index out of range'".

If I delete the line

> sgdDatabases.RowCount := sgdDatabases.RowCount + 1;

from the code, it displays both databases, but only shows the first four rows from the database even if there's more.

(I am aware of the uselessly repeated code and no I can't use anything else other than TStringGrid)

Comment: 1) If you single-step through your code in the debugger, on what **exact** line does the exception occur?  2) "for j := 0 to sgdDatabases.rowCount do
sgdDatabases.ColWidths[j] := 100;" looks strange to me - the index to ColWidths is a column number, so where does rowCount come into it?

Comment: See, that's what out teacher told us to do. I changed "for j := 0 to sgdDatabases.rowCount" to "for j := 0 to 8" because that's the number of columns and it's working, in a way. It displays the data from the Customer data in the Employee data if the number of rows if different in both.

Comment: @Martyn I think you could perhaps enter your findings as an answer?

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Wilco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line of your code looks wrong to me:

```
for j := 0 to sgdDatabases.rowCount do
  sgdDatabases.ColWidths[j] := 100;
```

The [Index] of a StringGrid's `ColWidths` property is a column number, not a row number, so `sgdDatabases.rowCount` should have nothing to do with it.  If, at the time the above code executes, the number of rows in the grid is greater than the number of columns, you will get an "Index out of range" error when the value of j reaches a value which represents an invalid column number.

In any case, even if that code were valid in that respect , there is an "off by one" error involving `sgdDatabases.rowCount`.  The row numbers are zero-based, so it should be `sgdDatabases.rowCount - 1` (assuming you were attempting to refer to a particular *row* by index, of course).

A more general point is that you can single-step through your code using the IDE's debugger; if you do that, you will see the exception occur when one particular line is executed, and that's the place to start looking for the cause.  You should always include the location of the exception in your SO question, because readers should not have to guess this.

Usually, the IDE debugger will find the exception even if you don't single-step, as long as you go to

`Tools | Debugger Options | Embarcadero Debuggers | Language Exceptions`

in the IDE and check the checkbox `Notify on Language Exceptions`.

Btw, it would be better if you wrote a general-purpose routine to populate a StringGrid from a Dataset, maybe along the following lines:

```
procedure TForm1.DatasetToGrid(Dataset : TDataset; Grid : TStringGrid);
var
  Col,
  Row : Integer;
begin

  Grid.RowCount := 1;
  Row := 0;

  // The following gives the column headers the names of the
  // Dataset fields.  
  for Col := 0 to Dataset.FieldCount - 1 do
    Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := Dataset.Fields[Col].FieldName;

  Inc(Row);
  Dataset.First;
  while not Dataset.Eof do begin
    for Col := 0 to Dataset.FieldCount - 1 do begin
      //  Oops! we don't need this Row := Grid.RowCount;
      Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := DataSet.Fields[Col].AsString;;
    end;
    Dataset.Next;
    Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount + 1;
    Inc(Row);
  end;
end;
```

One of the benefits of doing it that way is that all your mistakes are in one place, not duplicated in duplicated code, so if you fix them once, you're done.

Comment: Thank you. I made the procedure and the code looks a lot clearer and better.